# Loop counter prints same value each time with different input

Tags: c

So this loop is supposed to count the number of numerical chars in a line, but it prints the same value each time (6356732). What am I doing wrong?

```
if((i >= '0') && (i <= '9'))
    {
        printf("%c\n", i); 
        count = count++;        
    }
```

count is just declared 'int count = 0;'.

edit; I made a change suggested below but the output hasn't changed?

```
while(fscanf(f, "%c\n", &i) !=EOF) 
{
    if((i >= '0') && (i <= '9')) 
    {
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        printf("%c\n", i);
        count++;        
        sum++;
    }
}
```

edit 2; OK so I've got the program working as intended with the help of all you lovely folk! Thankyou very much!

```
 while(fscanf(f, "%c\n", &i) !=EOF) 
{
    if((i >= '0') && (i <= '9')) 
    {
        printf("%c\n", i); 
        count++;                

    }
}

count is defined at zero at the start of the program.
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole loop? In this snippet `i` isn't changing at all; so it's not surprising that it's printing the same value. Did you maybe mean to printf `count`?

Comment: @cbes You are initializing `count` to `0` each time you find a digit. You only need to initialize it once. Besides I don't see `i` is defined. You are reading in `f` but comparing with `i`?

Comment: where do you get  6356732? Nothing in yr code prints the count (which will always be zero in what you show)

Comment: Yeah I've removed the count=0. However, count is still ending up with a value of '6356732'. 

Count is being printed outside the loop, further down in main().

Also the values of i are saved in a text file earlier in the process, this loop is reading from the file and printing the results to the console.

Comment: `count = 0` should go before the `while` loop. Is your `printf` producing the characters you expect to see?

Comment: @cbes I can't see how exactly you read from the file and count. I have updated my answer with an example that should help to see the problem in your code and you can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: printf seems to be working perfectly. I'll attach an image of the [output](http://i.imgur.com/GVF5YWf.png)

Comment: add the code that prints out `count` to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `count++;` or `count = count + 1;`, because `count = count++;` is not defined. You can read more about the subject in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior).

Answer (score 3):

```
count = count++;
```

is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
For your purpose, you just need:

```
count++;
```

---

Here's a simple example to read a line from stdin and count chars (which you can easily modify to suit your file reading and counting):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{   
    char line[256];
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
       while(line[i]) {
          if((line[i] >= '0') && (line[i] <= '9')) { 
             printf("%c\n", line[i]); 
             count++; 
             sum = sum + line[i] - '0';
          }
          i++;
       }  
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", sum, count);
    return 0;
}
```